# Passenger + Rails + nginx + EC2 Linux AMI Errno::EACCES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set up an EC2 Linux AMI with Passenger + Rails. After much trouble, I have gotten nginx to serve out passenger but I am getting an error: Errno::EACCES

I am desperately hoping that this is some stupid setup problem. I am no sysadmin. Any help would be much appreciated and if you would like to see any more information, I am more than willing to comply.

EDIT: I dunno if this will help, but I am running passenger like so (in my applications root directory): 
`sudo /usr/local/bin/passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 80 -d -e development`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to `chown` the directory to ec2-user and then run it with `sudo /usr/local/bin/passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 80 -d -e development --user=ec2-user`

Why is rails such a nightmare to install!?